# dependencyManagement and version of dependencies

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, maven-2, pom.xml

In the pom file I have the dependencyManagement tag (could be also inherited from parent) and i would like to know how this tag can influence the version of dependencies. so let show an exemple:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

In the exemple below what version of the hamcrest-core dependency will be used? the version 2.2 or 1.0?

Comment: `mvn dependency:tree` will show you the dependencies used. (note that there's no such thing as hamcrest-core 1.0, as far as I can tell)

Comment: thanks, where to get mvn ? I m completely new to maven :(

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/install.html

Comment: @tgdavies Yes i Did but this didn't work :(  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74339839/with-mvn-how-to-get-the-dependencytree-of-a-library-from-its-pom

Answer (score 0):

**dependencies** defined in the pom should get priority over **dependencyManagement**.

Using **dependencyManagement** is useful when you have child projects under a parent project,

Dependencies specified in the parent pom **dependencies** section will always be included as a dependency of the child modules.

Dependencies specified in the **dependencyManagement** section, will only be included in the child module if they were also specified in the **dependencies** section of the child module.
You can specify the version and scope in the parent, but you can leave them out when specifying the dependencies in the child POM (to ensure all projects are using same version).